# Fractal Analysis

Tags: fractals

Is there any way to compare two fractals and analyse the difference between the two. I'm doing a project on fractals and It'll be very easy if there is a module which can be used to analyse and compare fractals! Does such a thing exists?

Comment: What kind of difference are you interested in?

Comment: Of course, there are many ways to compare two fractals. You'll need to be more specific to get a good answer.  Do you have any particular fractal sets in mind?  What kind of properties are you interested in?  What is your background?

Comment: Perhaps the most fundamental way to compare two fractals would be by their dimension.

Comment: Maybe [**this discussion**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13125/measuring-fractal-dimension-of-natural-objects-from-digital-images) can help you.